# sapui5 table data into PDF format

Tags: javascript

How do I convert the table data into PDF format in sapui5, I have tried the code below.

```
handlePdf: function() {
  var tabledata = oTable.getModel().getData();
  this.JSONToPDFConvertor(tabledata);
},
JSONToPDFConvertor: function(JSONData) {
  var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;
  var columns = new Array;
  for (var index in arrData[0]) {
    var rows = new Array;
    console.log(arrData);
    for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
      rows[i] = new Array;
      for (var j = 0; j < arrData.length;) {
        for (var index in arrData[0]) {
          rows[i][j] = arrData[i][index];
          j++;
        }
      }
    }
    if (columns.length < 4) {
      var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
    } else {
      var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt');
    }
    doc.autoTable(columns, rows);
    doc.save('table.pdf');
  }
}
```

Comment: To get any help, you're going to have to describe what that did, and how it didn't match what you want.

Comment: in this code  var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt'); new jsPDF is undefined its throwing an error its not taking that syntax.